# Which scientific names designate eyespots?

Tags: database

I've found that names containing *ocellata‎* and *ocellatus‎* designate species that feature [eyespots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyespot_(mimicry)). Are there other words in the scientific names that designate eyespots?

The problem I need to solve is: I want to fill the category [Eye shapes in nature](http://Category:Eye%20shapes%20in%20nature), therefore any method for finding such species is welcomed.

Comment: Eyespot is a scientific name. Other names: false eyes, fake eyes.

Comment: *Octopus bimaculoides* ; *Raja binoculata*; You might want to do a regular expression search on `.*oc[ue]l.*`, e.g. *Oligosoma lineoocellatum*